# Setting a state in a functional component is saying the setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing this issue when I try to setShowHeaderTitle. The setState is initiated in the home route component and passed as props to this bodyPart component

```
  <div className = 'bodyPart-card'
        onClick={() => {
          setBodyPart(item);
          setShowHeaderTitle('Showing Results:');
          window.scrollTo({top: document.querySelector('#exercises').getBoundingClientRect().y+document.documentElement.scrollTop, behavior:'smooth'});}}>
          <img src={Icon} />
          <p>{item}</p>
        </div>
```

Error:
react-dom.development.js:4312 Uncaught TypeError: setShowHeaderTitle is not a function
at onClick (BodyPart.js:11:1)

Comment: Probably it is not passed as prop. Check what console.log prints for 'setShowHeaderTitle'. Check if console.log(setShowHeaderTitle) prints 'undefined'

Comment: Can you provide the Full code for BodyPart.js, want to see how you are using props

Comment: @OktayYuzcan it is returning an object with name: bound dispatchSetState

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani I passed it correctly because it returned dispatchSetState

Answer (score 0):

Try adding both of the setState functions inside of a handleClick function. Then call that handleClick function on click

Comment: I don't get what you mean !?